# $\bigcap_{i \in I}\overline{co}(A_i)=\overline{co}\left(\bigcap_{i \in I}\overline{A_i}\right)$

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, convex-hulls

Let $(A_i: i \in I)$ be a family of sets in a topological vector space such that for all $i,j \in I$ there exists $k \in I$ for which $A_i \cap A_j=A_k$. Denote by $\overline{co}(X)$ the closure of the convex hull of $X$. Is it true that
$$
\bigcap_{i \in I}\overline{co}(A_i)=\overline{co}\left(\bigcap_{i \in I}\overline{A_i}\right)\,\,\,?
$$

One inclusion: Since $\overline{A_i} \subseteq \overline{co}(A_i)$ for all $i$ then $\bigcap_i \overline{A_i} \subseteq \bigcap_i \overline{co}(A_i)$. Therefore
$$
\overline{co}\left(\bigcap_i \overline{A_i}\right) \subseteq \overline{co}\left(\bigcap_i \overline{co}(A_i)\right)=\bigcap_i \overline{co}(A_i).
$$

What about the other?

---

**Comment 1.** The hypothesis on the family $\{A_i:i \in I\}$ is necessary, see Kavi's answer.

**Comment 2.** The claim is easily seen to be verified if $\{A_i: i \in I\}$ has a minimum, which holds, e.g., if $I$ is finite.

**Comment 3.** The claim $\bigcap_{i}\overline{co}(A_i)=\overline{co}\left(\bigcap_{i}A_i\right)$ (i.e., replacing $\overline{A_i}$ with $A_i$ in the right side) is false. As a counterexample, let $A_i=(0,2^{-i})\cup\{1\}$ for all integers $i\ge 1$. Then the left side is $[0,1]$ and the right side is $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is due to [Salvo Tringali](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/20748/salvo-tringali).

The claim is false. For each positive integer $n$ let $A_n$ be the set of integers with absolute value greater than $n$. Then the left hand side is $\mathbf{R}$ and the right hand side is $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for an earlier version of the question.

Let $A=\{1,4\}, B=\{2,3\}$. The RHS is empty. But $co(A)=[1,4],co(B)=[2,3]$ so $2 \in LHS$.