# $\bigcap_{i}\mathrm{co}(A_i)=\mathrm{co}(\bigcap_{i}A_i)$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, convex-hulls

Let $(A_i: i \in I)$ be a family of closed sets contained in $[0,1]$ such that for all $i,j \in I$ there exists $k \in I$ for which $A_i \cap A_j=A_k$. Denote by $\mathrm{co}(X)$ the convex hull of $X$. Is it true that
$$
\bigcap_{i \in I}\mathrm{co}(A_i)=\mathrm{co}\left(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i\right)\,\,\,?
$$

Ps. Here a [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048090/bigcap-i-in-i-overlinecoa-i-overlineco-left-bigcap-i-in-i-overli) question. Here, under weaker conditions, it is already shown that the right hand side is always contained in the left hand side. I guess a positive answer also on the converse inclusion.

Comment: What happens when you try to prove it?  Can you show the left is a subset of the right?  Can you show the right is a subset of the left?   --> In this forum, you should show your work when you pose a question.  If you do not, the question may be "put on hold" until you do.

Comment: I already proved in the related link that RHS is a subset of LHS, under weaker conditions. However, the related question is false. A counterexample will be posted soon; on the other hand, the sets were not bounded. Here, assuming that each $A_i$ is compact you can use, by the Caratheodory theorem, that operators closure and conv commute. Hence the identity simplifies to the above one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse inclusion holds for any family $(A_i: i \in I)$ of compact subsets of a (Hausdorff) locally convex topological vector space $V$ (over $\Bbb R$). Indeed, let $a\in V\setminus \mathrm{co}\left(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i\right)$. By [Hahn–Banach separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem)  there exists a continuous linear map $\lambda : V\to \Bbb R$ and $t \in\Bbb R$ such that $\lambda(a) < t < \lambda (b)$ for all $b\in \mathrm{co}\left(\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i\right)$. Therefore $U=\lambda^{-1}(t,\infty)$ is a convex open subset of $V$ containing $\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i$ but not containing $a$. By so-called generalized Shura-Bura’s lemma, there exists a finite subset $J$  of $I$ such that $\bigcap_{i \in J}A_i\subset U$ (indeed, otherwise $(A_i\setminus U: i \in I)$ is a centered family of compact sets with empty intersection). Since  $\bigcap_{i \in J}A_i=A_j$ for some $j\in I$, we have $\mathrm{co} A_j\subset U\subset V\setminus\{a\}$.